# Load thumbnails for video - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, thumbnails

In JavaFx we can load images easily from an external server:

```
imageView.setImage(new Image("http://...File.png"));
```

But is there a way to load the thumbnail of videos?
Something like: `imageView.setImage(new Image("http://...File.mp4"));`

I'm developing something like a "gallery" and would like to load the thumbnails of videos coming straight from my server, is it possible?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  However, the obvious approach would be to capture one frame of the video (hopefully one that makes sense) turn it into an image, and then create a thumbnail for the image.

Comment: @StephenC But how do you make a video that is not local without downloading it altogether? Of course, the way I set an example does not make sense, because it is an EXAMPLE, if that were the case and it worked, I would not have to open an issue here

Answer (score 1):

An mp3 or mp4 file can have an embedded thumbnail image as part of its metadata.   There are third party libraries for reading mp3 / mp4 metadata.  For example:

- [How to retrieve thumbnail picture of an mp3 file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374592/how-to-retrieve-thumbnail-picture-of-an-mp3-file-using-java)
- [App Engine Java - Extract thumbnail from mp4 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315479/app-engine-java-extract-thumbnail-from-mp4-video)

If the file *doesn't* have a thumbnail, then you could conceivably pick a frame of the video and use it as a thumbnail, but the chances of picking an appropriate frame (i.e. one that is indicative of the movie) without the assistance of a human being are not great.  But here is an example:

- [Extract Thumbnail for specific second from MP4 file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555532/extract-thumbnail-for-specific-second-from-mp4-file-in-android)

---

> But how do you make a video that is not local without downloading it altogether?

Approach #1: pick a 3rd-party metadata extraction library that can operate in stream mode.  The metadata should be at / near the start of the stream.

Approach #2: get the server to do the extraction, and present you with the thumbnail separately from the main video.

Comment: Ty dude, soon when I wake up I'll try and give you the return, thank you again ;)